# How to insert image in wordpress post title?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to know how to put an image into the wordpress title, only by the backend. At the moment is use the Wordpress-URL in my code like this:

```
<img 
 src="http://wp.cloudstarter.de/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/logo-cloudshare.png" 
/>
```

But I want to control, remove and replace my picture just in the Backend. Right now, i just did not figure it out yet how to use my Images in the title of a specific post.

Comment: why you want to use image into title?

Comment: Because it should be an image to a product and my client especially wants it there. BTW, first time i am working with wordpress, so i am a total newbie there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display the image next to post title, you may need to add [Custom fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Custom_Fields) and edit the post title showing template(usually content-page.php) to integrate the custom field. So when adding the post you need to set the image in the custom field and as title showing part contains the script to display the image, the title will be displayed with the image.

Comment: Thank you very much! This together with `<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'systems', true); ?>` solved all my problems!

Answer (score 0):

> get your header.php code. You can find the code by editing the
>   header.php file.
>
> To edit the file:
>
> 1) Login to WP admin panel
>
> 2) Click Appearance in the left sidebar
>
> 3) Click Editor
>
> 4) In this page click on the header.php link (to edit the file) in the
>   right side of the screen.
>
> 5) Copy the code and paste in this forum.
>
> Put the code between Your code here

Comment: I think you missunderstood my question (or did i missunderstand your tip here?). The header already has an image and all works fine. I want a special post to have an imagie in its title - so that i have the the image as part of the title.